# Additional divs added by webmarix

Tags: webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I just created my first Hello World ASP Web Pages site using Webmatrix.

I launched it in a browser and realised that there are additional divs ans scripts added to my page.
The odd thing is that Ctr+U gives me the clean page source as expected, but in FireBug I can see crap like:

```
<div id="_GPL_e6a00_parent_div" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; z-index: 2147483647;">
<object id="_GPL_e6a00_swf" width="1" height="1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/e6a00/storage.swf?r=1">
...
</div>
```

Any idea how and when it's generated and how to switch it off?
(It's the same in Opera and Explorer...)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can see it in Firebug doesn't mean that WebMatrix generated it. That looks like something a FireFox add-on has generated. Switch off your add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I just bumped into the same 
   http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/e6a00/storage.swf?r=1
getting injected into my FireFox.  I found it after doing a manual cleanup of my FlashBlock whitelist.  It turns out that, at least in my case, it was being injected by an extension called TornTV, which itself seems to be part of some grander TornTV presence on my machine, which was hard to uninstall.  I ended up having to use Revo uninstaller to get it to go away.  No idea how malicious it actually is - it wasn't spotted by McAfee - but I nuked it.